# How do i connect nodejs app with mongodb in google cloud platform

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-cloud-platform

```
var db = monk('103.196.212.147:27017',  {
  username : 'app_staging',
  password : 'jimmy@16'
});
```

this is the connection string we used

Comment: I hope that is not your real password...

Comment: No its not real password :)  thanks greuze

Answer (score 0):

In [Google Cloud getting started](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/deploy-mongodb), they say you must specify some config before running your application:

```
{
  "GCLOUD_PROJECT": "[YOUR_PROJECT_ID]",
  "DATA_BACKEND": "mongodb",
  "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://[YOUR_MONGODB_IP_ADDRESS]:27017/mydb",
  "MONGO_COLLECTION": "books"
}
```

Maybe you want to take a look to [Structured Data example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-getting-started/tree/master/2-structured-data), in particular to [config.js](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-getting-started/blob/master/2-structured-data/config.js), where the magic is done (read from environment variables).